# How to find the most specific match from a list of regex patterns?

Tags: c++, regex

I have a series of regex patterns, and am matching incoming HttpRequest paths to these. I would like to iterate through them and find the **most specific match** (a URI may match more than one regex pattern).

For example `"/static/images/foo.jpg"` would match three of following regex patterns I have:

```
^/
^/static/images/
^/static/
^/echo/$
```

How can I iterate through the list, and determine that the most specific match is `^/static/images/`?

---

For the sake of simplicity, let's assume "most specific" here means **most characters or sub-patterns matched, reading from left to right**. I realize that if we introduce something like the following regex, "most specific" becomes ambiguous:

```
.*\.(jpg|png)$
```

Comment: Since the criteria are somewhat hard to specify, why not order them (in your code) least-to-most-specific. Loop through all the patterns, keeping track of the *last* (and therefore, most-specific) matched pattern.

Comment: Yup, as you identified, there's no meaningful way to identify specificity in general.  You have degenerate cases where you can apply the criterion "longest regex", so just do what @Paul suggested.

Comment: @PaulRoub Yes, I agree. However, I'm getting these patterns from a user-editable configuration file. Worst case, I was going to specify that they be ordered, but was looking for a way to ensure this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As mentionned in the comments - there's no definitive way to settle the problem other than manually. However you can do a few things to come up with a semi-heuristic algorithm that theoretically can at least help you in your particular case:

1. You can test the length of the pattern. In the example longest = most specific, and although that's not always the case, it can at least give an idea,
2. You can test the patterns agains themselves. For example - `^/static/` fits in `^/static/images/`, so `^/static/images/` is more specific,
3. You can keep track of how many URIs already matched a particular pattern. The less URIs match a pattern - the more specific it is.

Answer (score 0):

You would use alternation.

You scale specificity from left to right.

1 - most specific
4 - least specific

```
(^/static/images/|^/static/|^/|^/echo/$)
         1            2      3     4
```

If it matches 1, it will not bother with 2,3, and 4.

Comment: How can I know which it matched?

Comment: This solution still requires to sort via specificity. The problem is how to decide which pattern is most specific during run-time from what I understood.